# New Scientist Enigma 1779

Tags: trigonometry, logic, recreational-mathematics

I drew four right-angled triangles. The hypotenuse of my first triangle was also the shortest side of my second triangle; the hypotenuse of my second triangle was also the shortest side of my third triangle; the hypotenuse of my third triangle was also the shortest side of my fourth triangle. The length in millimetres of each side of each triangle was an integer less than 100.

How do you solve this?

*What were the lengths of the shortest and the longest sides that I drew?

Comment: Was it really all 4 triangles with integer sides all less than 100, or just the first 3?

Comment: I go along with @GeoffRobinson. I think we have a sequence 2,3,5,12,13,84,85, x with x larger than 100

Comment: Definitely all 4.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, reinbot: I'll give you a hint - the shortest side of all is 9 mm, and the longest is 97 mm.

Comment: @TonyK: okay, now I got it ;-)

Comment: @TonyK: Thanks, but I didn't want a hint. I just wanted to make sure I was looking at the right question!

Comment: Yeah once you see that hint it's game over =).